# Cannot run opencv using cmake.How to start?

Tags: c++, bash, opencv, cmake

I am following the tutorial of running `cmake` .

the first step is:

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

I am getting error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `VERSION'

I tried writing :

> 'cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)'

and it says:

> command not found.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run this command in your shell rather than putting it in `CMakeLists.txt` and running cmake. I suggest you try to find a tutorial that is more explicit on where and how to run what.

Comment: In the title of your question you mention openCV. Is this related to your CMake problems? Or is it just CMake? Or do you want to build openCV which uses CMake? Please ask your question more precise.